# Entity Framework 4.1 count identical database rows

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-relationship

### My setup

I have two classes, here shown stripped down to what is needed in this example:

```
public class Photo : Entity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    public Photo()
    {
        Tags = new List<Tag>();
    }
}


public class Tag : Entity
{
    [Key]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }

    public Tag()
    {
        Photos = new List<Photo>();
    }
}
```

As shown above theres is a **many-to-many relationship** between the two entities.

I'm using EF 4.1 code-first.

Example:

- "**photo1**" has "**tag1**", "**tag2**" and "**tag3**" in its tags navigation property.
- "**photo2**" has "**tag2**", "**tag3**" and "**tag4**" in its tags navigation property.
- "**photo3**" has "**tag2**" and "**tag4**" in its tags navigation property.

Total tag count in all photos:

- "tag1": 1
- "tag2": 3
- "tag3": 2
- "tag4": 2
- Total tags: 8

### Note

My end goal is this tag cloud, but using MVC3:

http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View960C74AE-D01B-428E-BCF3-E57B85D5A308.htm

### First question

How do I (using EF) find out how many times the most used tag(s) is used (finding the count of "**tag2**")?
And the same for the least used tag(s) (count of "**tag1**" in above example).

**In the link above** these to lines of code is used:

```
double.TryParse(tagData.Compute("min(count)", null).ToString(), out min);
double.TryParse(tagData.Compute("max(count)", null).ToString(), out max);
```

*What is the EF/LINQ equivalent?*

### Second question

How do I get the count for each tag or the count for the 50 most used tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Counts by tag:**

```
from t in Context.Tags
select new
{
    t.Text,
    t.Photos.Count()
}
```

**Most used tag:**

```
(from t in Context.Tags
let photoCount = t.Photos.Count()
orderby photoCount descending
select new
{
    t.Text,
    photoCount
}).FirstOrDefault()
```

**50 most used tags (may not actually have 50 there):**

```
(from t in Context.Tags
let photoCount = t.Photos.Count()
orderby photoCount descending
select new
{
    t.Text,
    photoCount
}).Take(50)
```

Freehand, so might not be 100% syntactically correct or the smallest/most readable way to do it.

**Edit: Added Example:**

```
foreach(var result in Context.Tags.Select(x => new { t.Text, t.Photos.Count() }))
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Text: {0}, Count: {1}", result.Text, result.Count.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks good. Can you illustrate it further with an example of how to loop through all the found tags and their count?

Comment: Works great! Is theres a simpler way to get only the lowest tag count and the highest?

Comment: Do you just need the number? or do you want the number and the tag text?

Comment: Figured it out: `int minCount = result.Min(x => x.Count);`.